# Copying a MAT image to specific address in c++

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, memcpy

I'm trying to copy a MAT image loaded in from a file to a specific address location. I have the following code

```
int main()
{

    cv::Mat inImg =    cv::imread("M6_traffic.jpg");

    //Data point copy
    unsigned char * pData = (unsigned char *)inImg.data;
    unsigned char * Dest   = (unsigned char *)0x0f000000;;

    int width = inImg.rows;
    int height = inImg.cols;

    //data copy using memcpy function
    memcpy(Dest, pData, sizeof(unsigned char)*width*height*3);

}
```

But when I run this it always crashes, any idea why? and is there a better why to do this? My end goal is to able to copy a image data to specific address in a Linux based system

Comment: You should add details of the crash, error given etc. What line does it crash on? There are lots of details you have missed out that help answer your question. I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reworking your question

Comment: _"My end goal is to able to copy a image data to specific address in a Linux based system"_ Why? That's another area where I think more background is needed. Does your system provide any kind of allowance for you copying to that address? Most modern OSes do not allow stuffing data into arbitrary addresses in memory.

Comment: ... and that is the reason for your crash.

Comment: in addition to everything said, please mind, that cols is the width and rows is the height of the image. That is in general not important for copying, but probably for using the image later on after copying. There is another problem in your code. It isn't guaranteed, that images are continuous. For example for optimization reasons, images might have a padding at the end of each row. You should make sure, that the image is continuous (e.g. by calling .clone() and/or testing .isContinuous).

Answer (score 1):

propably there is no allocated memory on address 0x0f000000.
and you cannot force this to be a valid address

Allocate the right size of memory with malloc and it will work.
The OS then determines your address space and returns a pointer to it.

```
unsigned char* Dest = malloc(sizeof(pData));
memcpy(Dest, pData, sizeof(pData))
```

Comment: So by doing this 

    unsigned char * Dest   = (unsigned char *)0x0f000000;;
    Dest = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*width*height*3);

The OS will assign Dest to a different address on the second line? I'm trying to copy the data to specfic virtual address which I know matches a physical address which I need for use in some FPGA logic, is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

0x0f000000 is essentially a null pointer. What you're trying to do is copy data into a memory address that has not been set with `memcpy(Dest, pData, sizeof(unsigned char)*width*height*3);`.

You should allocate memory for `Dest` before your `memcpy` statement. You can do this with either `malloc` or `calloc`. These function calls are described in the following links. Hope this helps!

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/